# How to save numpy array images and put them into a single folder?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy, python-imaging-library

I have a numpy array containing 5000 28 by 28 images (5000,28,28). I want to save all these images as jpg files and save them all in a single folder. What is the fastest and most efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: It depends what sort of a machine you are running on. The answer is vastly different for a single core Raspberry Pi Zero and an 8-core desktop with SSD disks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried writing 50,000 images of 28x28 to disk as JPEG using:

- sequential code (25seconds)
- multi-threaded code (19 seconds)
- multi-processing code (5 seconds)

on a 12-core MacBook Pro with SSDs. Times are given in parentheses after each item in list above.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import imageio
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def WriteOne(i,data):
    """Write a single image to disk"""
    #print(f"WriteOne called with i={i}")
    imageio.imwrite(f"image-{i:04d}.jpg", data)

def WriteSequential(images):
    """Write all images sequentially to disk"""
    print("Sequential")
    for i, data in enumerate(images):
        WriteOne(i, data)
    return

def WriteIndices(p):
    """Write given index to disk as JPEG"""
    #print(f"WriteIndices {p[0]}")
    WriteOne(p[0], p[1])
    return

def WriteMultiThread(images):
    """Write all images  to disk with multi-threading"""
    print("MultiThread")
    nThreads = 8
    with ThreadPool(nThreads) as pool:
        pool.map(WriteIndices, list(enumerate(images)))
    return

def WriteMultiProcess(images):
    """Write all images  to disk with multi-processing"""
    print("MultiProcess")
    nProcesses = 8
    with Pool(nProcesses) as pool:
        pool.map(WriteIndices, list(enumerate(images)))
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Synthesize 50000 images, each 28x28
    N = 50000
    images = np.random.randint(0,256,(N,28,28), dtype=np.uint8)

    WriteSequential(images)

    WriteMultiThread(images)

    WriteMultiProcess(images)
```