# What is the most efficient way of processing big images once and store the results to use them later?

Tags: python, performance, opencv, generator, processing-efficiency

I'm refactoring [stitching_detailed.py](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/opencv/blob/stitching_detailed_refactor/samples/python/stitching_detailed.py) of OpenCVs Stitcher API. The User of this Program can choose the amount of Images which are going to be stitched together. I have historical high resolution scans (TIF) with each of up to 300 MP to be stitched, so memory management is important since I might run into an cv::OutOfMemoryError. Additionally the program should be as effective as possible in regard to computation time and memory usage.

I need to work with different image sizes in different parts of the Workflow. I need to work with the medium resolution first to make some estimations, then the low resolutions for other estimations and finally the full images. However, I have performance issues with my actual approach. I measure the performance with:

```
import time
from functools import wraps
import tracemalloc
import cv2
import numpy as np

def performance_test(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        tracemalloc.start()
        start = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        current, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
        print(f"Peak was {peak / 10**6} MB")
        end = time.time()
        print(f"Time was {end - start} s")
        tracemalloc.stop()
        return result
    return wrapper
```

Create some dummy images:

```
img_names = ["dummy1.png", "dummy2.png", "dummy3.png"]
image = np.zeros((10000, 10000, 3), np.uint8)
image[:] = (0, 0, 255)
for img_name in img_names:
    cv2.imwrite(img_name, image)
```

The most memory friendly approach is to load the images where I need them:

```
def process_medium_resolution_images(img_names):
    for big_image in img_names:
        high = cv2.imread(big_image)
        medium = cv2.resize(high, (5000, 5000))
        print(medium.shape)

def process_low_resolution_images(img_names):
    for big_image in img_names:
        high = cv2.imread(big_image)
        low = cv2.resize(high, (1000, 1000))
        print(low.shape)

def process_high_resolution_images(img_names):
    for big_image in img_names:
        high = cv2.imread(big_image)
        print(high.shape)

@performance_test
def main(img_names):
    process_medium_resolution_images(img_names)
    process_low_resolution_images(img_names)
    process_high_resolution_images(img_names)

main(img_names)
# Peak was 675.149574 MB
# Time was 8.497036933898926 s
```

I can also read the files in one place and store them in lists. This improves the computation time, but comes with the downside of more memory used, which can lead to problems in my case.

```
def img_reading_and_processing(img_names):
    high_imgs, medium_imgs, low_imgs = [], [], []
    for big_image in img_names:
        high = cv2.imread(big_image)
        high_imgs.append(high)
        medium = cv2.resize(high, (5000, 5000))
        medium_imgs.append(medium)
        low = cv2.resize(high, (1000, 1000))
        low_imgs.append(low)
    return high_imgs, medium_imgs, low_imgs

def process_imgs(imgs):
    for img in imgs:
        print(img.shape)

@performance_test
def main2(img_names):
    high_imgs, medium_imgs, low_imgs = img_reading_and_processing(img_names)
    process_imgs(medium_imgs)
    process_imgs(low_imgs)
    process_imgs(high_imgs)

main2(img_names)
# Peak was 1134.155195 MB
# Time was 2.8256263732910156 s
```

I'm looking for a way to combine the advantages of both solutions.

**EDIT**: Based on @balmiy's comment I tried to write the intermediate results on disk and reload them later:

```
def img_reading_and_processing(img_names):
    for idx, big_image in enumerate(img_names):
        high = cv2.imread(big_image)
        medium = cv2.resize(high, (5000, 5000))
        low = cv2.resize(high, (1000, 1000))
        cv2.imwrite(f"medium{idx}.png", medium)
        cv2.imwrite(f"low{idx}.png", low)

def process_medium_resolution_images2(img_names):
    for idx, img in enumerate(img_names):
        medium = cv2.imread(f"medium{idx}.png")
        print(medium.shape)

def process_low_resolution_images2(img_names):
    for idx, img in enumerate(img_names):
        low = cv2.imread(f"low{idx}.png")
        print(low.shape)

@performance_test
def main3(img_names):
    process_medium_resolution_images2(img_names)
    process_low_resolution_images2(img_names)
    process_high_resolution_images(img_names)

main3(img_names)
# Peak was 678.149341 MB
# Time was 6.7737205028533936 s
```

We see that computation time reduced a bit while the Memory Usage remained small. However not close to how fast it is to keep it in lists

Comment: Presumably the resize is the expensive operation; why not save the resized images on disk so no need to recompute and you re-read the already-resized from disk when needed. If that's still slower than you want then you'll have to start keeping some in memory, perhaps a least recently used cache so little used images are discarded (but are still on disk if needed). Don't save resized images to disk in JPEG format because that's expensive to write and read (and its lossy); use a simpler and lossless  format like PNG.

Comment: It's very hard to say when we have 1) no idea how many images you have 2) no idea how big they are nor what format 3) no idea what processing you need to do 4) no idea how much memory or how many cores you have...

Comment: @balmy I will try this and update the question if I have the results

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm refactoring stitching_detailed.py of OpenCVs Stitcher API: https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/opencv/blob/stitching_detailed_refactor/samples/python/stitching_detailed.py. So 1) the User can choose the amount of Images which are going to be stitched together. 2) I have historical high resolution scans of 15000 x 20000 = 300,000,000 pixels to be stitched, they are in TIF format, however the program should be generic for all image types. 3) Stitching 4) Does it matter?

Comment: In general, if you don't **need** multiple images in memory all at the same time, then don't load more than one at a time in an enormous list. In general, if you have lots of small/medium images to process, try and do them in parallel with multi-processing or multi-threading.

Comment: I updated the question with real image data on the Disk (I should have done that earlier)

Comment: @MarkSetchell but it's so much faster :( and I have no experience with multi-processing/multi-threading...

Comment: There's a simple example here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59473323/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the example! But I don't think including multithreading is reasonalble when updating OpenCV samples which should be as easy to understand as possible...

Comment: It's a tradeoff, you're basically asking to have the cake and eat it too. | Regarding your last comment, again a tradeoff -- you want a simple to understand sample, or an optimized, highly performing solution?.

Comment: "However not close to how fast it is to keep it in lists" - well yes, but you have oodles more disk space than memory space. There's no such thing as a free lunch; memory: fast, expensive. Disk: slow, cheap. So choose.

Comment: Yeah I begin to understand that this is a typical "free lunch" problem.. Thank you all for your inputs!